# When finding the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ on $(-1,1)$, how to interpret solution $y = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}<-\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

Consider the task of finding the inverse function of the function $y=f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ on $(-1,1)$.

One way is to try to isolate $x$ as a function of $y$. Sometimes it's easier to do this by switching the names of the variables and isolating $y$ as a function of $x$. $y=f^{-1}(x)$ is now the inverse of our original function.

$$x=\frac{y}{1-y^2}$$

$$xy^2+y-x=0\tag{1}$$

If $x=0$ then $y=0$

If $x\neq 0$ then we find that

$$y = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}$$

are candidate solutions.

$y = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}$ is the correct one. We can tell because in the original function, positive $x$ maps to positive $f(x)$ and negative $x$ maps to negative $f(x), and this behavior must be present in the inverse function. It is for this solution but not for the other solution.

My question here is about the (incorrect) solution to the problem

$$y = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}\tag{2}$$

**Why exactly is it present?**

Here is my attempt at an idea of why it might be present.

The function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is actually defined everywhere except at $1$ and $-1$. The graph looks like

[[image: Graph of <span class=]$f$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZdBJ.png)

Does $(2)$ have something to do with the inverse of the portion of the graph of $f$ with $|x|>1$.

Note that since $\sqrt{1+4x^2}>1$ for $x\neq0$, then $-1-\sqrt{1+4x^2}<2$ and so

$$y = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}<-\frac{1}{x} \text{ for } x>0$$

$$y = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}>-\frac{1}{x} \text{ for } x<0$$

Comment: You need to change the last inequality from $<$ to $>$ when $x<0$, but otherwise you are spot on.The additional "solution" lies on those branches where $x>1$ or $x<-1$. Note that, while solving the quadratic equation, you never used the condition $-1<x<1$ so it is expected that you will get all the solutions from the entire curve.

Comment: @StinkingBishop When we look at the graph pictured above, we see that the portions at $|x|>1$ are inverses of one another. The inverse of that part would be exactly like that part, no? And yet $(2)$ doesn't seem to correspond to the graph above at $|x|>1$, it rather looks like $-\frac{1}{x}$, just slightly shifted downwards. Ie the vertical asymptote of $(2)$ is at $0$, not $\pm 1$.

Comment: Don't mix up your $x$ and your $y$. The *horizontal* asymptote of (2) is expected to be $1$ (and also $-1$), which you see when, on your graph above, swap the $x$ and $y$ axis.

Comment: True. Silly mistake!